# Algorithm for converting complex sine wave to constituent simple sine waves

Tags: algorithms, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis, music-theory

Since any real sound is by nature a complex sine wave based on the harmonic series, every sound is made up of many simple sine waves. Since a sound is constructed via the combination of these waves, it would be nice to have an algorithm to deconstruct the waves as well.

Prove or disprove that it is possible to define an algorithm that takes as input the equation that represents a complex sine wave made with some number, n, harmonics, or constituent simple sine waves, and outputs each individual simple sine wave's parameters (frequency, amplitude, etc...). Also, if possible, construct the algorithm (though a non-constructive proof is acceptable for proof or disproof).

For example, given the equation for the following complex sine wave, determine the parameters for each individual harmonic that makes it up.
[image: Complex sine wave example - obtained from: https://www.ams.jhu.edu/dan-mathofmusic/sound-waves/]

You may assume that the 'music' is static over time (unlike the above picture), such as an instrument holding (perfectly) a tone.

Note, [***this***](https://knowm.org/complex-sine-wave-prediction/) website has a pseudo-tangential heuristic solution, and [***this***](http://www.planetoftunes.com/sound-audio-theory/complex-soundwaves.html#.WuX4StPwbBI) site might provide some background.

Comment: Forgot about this question, it seems the solution is Discrete Fourier Transforms, or DFTs. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform